# What should be the permission of data folder for postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

My postgres is using this hba file

`/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/pg_hba.conf`

But i can't go in `/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data` folder, it says permission denied and these are permissions of all files

```
total 92
drwx------ 19 postgres postgres  4096 Jan 27 15:05 base
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 Jan 27 22:42 global
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 Apr 25  2013 pg_clog
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  4377 Jan 27 22:57 pg_hba.conf
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  1636 Apr 25  2013 pg_ident.conf
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 May  2  2013 pg_log
drwx------  4 postgres postgres  4096 Apr 25  2013 pg_multixact
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 Jan 27 17:34 pg_notify
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 Apr 25  2013 pg_serial
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 Jan 27 23:01 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 Apr 25  2013 pg_subtrans
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 Apr 25  2013 pg_tblspc
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 Apr 25  2013 pg_twophase
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres     4 Apr 25  2013 PG_VERSION
drwx------  3 postgres postgres  4096 Jan 27 15:05 pg_xlog
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 19136 Apr 27  2013 postgresql.conf
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres    71 Jan 27 17:34 postmaster.opts
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres    72 Jan 27 17:34 postmaster.pid
```

I want to know is that is this all right. or i need to change them

I am trying to restart

```
sudo service postgresql start
Starting postgresql service:                               [FAILED]
```

I want to see the why its failing but don't know where is the log file

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to go into that folder as root. Here's a stab in the dark as to what could be the issue at hand -- did you run `initdb -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data`?

To answer your question, the log file location is given in /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/postgresql.conf -- log_directory and log_filename, these are only used if the logging_collector is on.